# Problem to structure code permissions (ACL)

Tags: sql, permissions, api-design, access-control

I have a problem here to structure the code to validate the permissions.

Let's suppose I have three actions: *`read:own_users`*, *`read:my_users`*, *`read:all_users`*.

And I have a route *`get/users`*.

I want this route returning all users if the guy which is doing the request have *`read:all_users`*. But if he only have *`read:my_users`* permission, this route should return just the users that this guy inserted. And the last possibility, if the user just have *`read:own_users`* permission, I wants this route returning just your own object.

So, what I want to solve is: How to do that without doing a switch case in my code for every route putting a where in my SQL.

Or maybe I'm doing this by the wrong way and I need to plan all the stuff trying a new strategy.

Comment: You don't need a switch case, you just need a suitable WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you exemplify this to me? I never heard about suitable WHERE clause.

Comment: Something like `WHERE Permission = All_Users OR (Permission = My_Users AND InsertedBy = Me)`.

Comment: I got it, but in my case I have the permissions assigned to user inside the token not inside my database. My database just have the information.

Comment: Your database is the source of the secured information, not the token.   Let the database do the work of figuring out which records to serve.  Let the token do the work of providing the permissions.

Comment: I will try solve it through that way, thank you very much for the attention and for the help.